# OnFilenameChanged not being called

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

```
[QueryProperty("Filename", "Filename_")]
public partial class DetailsViewModel : ObservableObject
{

     [ObservableProperty]
     string filename;

     partial void OnFilenameChanged(string value)
     {
         ReadFile();
     }

     [Relay Command]
     async Task Edit(string s)
     {
         // filename passed as s
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{"Edit"}?Filename_{s}");
     }
}
```

I used this code to make sure the property was set instead of calling `ReadFile()` from the constructor where Filename is null which worked fine in my `DetailsViewModel` but when using the same idea in my `EditViewModel` the `OnFilenameChanged` method doesn't run at all.

```
[QueryProperty("Filename", "Filename_")]
public partial class EditViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     [ObservableProperty]
     string filename;

     partial void OnFilenameChanged(string value)
     {
         ReadFile();
     }
}
```

At first I thought the problem was with the `ReadFile()` method but I put a breakpoint on it and it's never called which means `OnFilenameChanged` is never called either. I've tried playing around with the variables, I stepped through it and s is the filename I want it to be when it's passed to the Edit command.

Comment: thats not how `ObservableProperty` works.  It raises a `PropertyChanged` event, it does not create individual events for each property.  See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#how-it-works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your property is never set and the `OnFilenameChanged()` method never gets called is that the `QueryProperty` doesn't match any of the properties in your *EditViewModel*.

The problem specifically is in this line:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{"Edit"}?Filename_{s}");
```

Note how you are missing an `=` character. It should be

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{"Edit"}?Filename_={s}");
```

Also note that only the value of `s` will be passed, the argument will not include `Filename_` in it.

Generally, I would recommend to not use the underscore (`_`) and change the `QueryProperty` to this:

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(Filename), nameof(Filename))]
public partial class EditViewModel : ObservableObject
{
     [ObservableProperty]
     string filename;

     partial void OnFilenameChanged(string value)
     {
         ReadFile();
     }
}
```

Then call it like this, for example:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"/Edit?Filename={s}");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the equals sign. I knew it was going to be something small that I'd missed but I just couldn't see it!

Answer (score -1):

```cs
[QueryProperty("Filename", "Filename_")]
    
public partial class EditViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string filename;
    
    partial void OnFilenameChanged(string value)
    {
        ReadFile();
    }
}
```

I think that it is the right way to solve this. there is no any issu